# Gaps and dislocations when connecting sprites

Tags: sprite, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to connect a few sprites together like this:
[image]
[image]

but everytime I zoom out, I get [gaps](https://i.ibb.co/PrZHC46/image.png) & [dislocations](https://i.ibb.co/r0qRGNW/untitled.png)
I've even tried turning off filter according to [this article](https://nathanielmorihara.medium.com/how-to-fix-gaps-between-tiles-in-godot-a0ec5e6096de) but I'm still getting the same problem.

Maybe I can fill the gaps with a little bit of padding and offset but the dislocations
are the main concern
how do I fix this? and make it seem & move like it's a single image?

Answer (score 0):

Your scene tree might be causing this problem. Your positions are all children of the one before. Make pos1, pos2 and pos3 siblings

Comment: nope that still didn't [help](https://i.ibb.co/Gvnm7LM/image.png)

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to check come to mind:

- Make sure the positions, rotation and scales are rounded and correct. You don't want an offset of a fraction of a pixel that would become whole pixels once zoom is applied.
- Pixel snapping can make it so the texture sometimes rounds up to the next pixel and sometimes down to the prior pixel. So try changing GPU Pixel Snapping: In Project Settings -> General -> Rendering -> 2d

---

Addendum: I want to mention that vertical tearing may look like that too. So double check vsync is enabled in Project Settings -> General -> Display -> Window -> Use Vsync.

---

And I'll give you an alternative: You can get a similar effect sin a `Line2D`, give it the texture you want, and set the texture mode (if you set it to tile make sure the texture was imported with repeat enabled). *You can manipulate the `points` property to change the shape of the `Line2D` from code.*

Comment: it was the GPU Pixel Snapping! I had to turn it off